# how can i convert a string to datetime with pyspark?

Tags: string, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, converters

this is my first question so I hope you can help me.

I have a dataframe pyspark created in databricks community

```
data=[["1","Feb 20 2017 4:52AM"],["2","Feb 20 2017 5:13AM"]]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,["id","input"])

df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

I would like to convert column "input" as a datetime or date (preferably datetime)

First, I'm trying to convert column "input" to timestamp but but I don't know if I'm going the wrong way. I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using it as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

df.withColumn("input_changed", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("input", 'MMM d yyyy HH:mma'),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm')).show()

+---+------------------+----------------+
| id|             input|   input_changed|
+---+------------------+----------------+
|  1|Feb 20 2017 4:52AM|02-20-2017 04:52|
|  2|Feb 20 2017 5:13AM|02-20-2017 05:13|
+---+------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.